# Serialize or encode proto member to byte array

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have proto members that look like this

```
String = "1324211127562612736"
Varint = 1
Varint = 10000000000
```

How could I serialize to byte array where the result should look like this?

```
0x0a, 0x13, 0x31, 0x33, 0x32, 0x34, 0x32, 0x31, 0x31, 0x31, 0x32, 0x37, 0x35, 0x36, 0x32, 0x36, 0x31, 0x32, 0x37, 0x33, 0x36, 0x20, 0x01, 0x28, 0x80, 0xc8, 0xaf, 0xa0, 0x25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By running the hex `0A133133323432313131323735363236313237333620012880C8AFA025` through https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode, we can see that we have:

```
Field #1: 0A String Length = 19, Hex = 13, UTF8 = "1324211127562612 ..." (total 19 chars)
Field #4: 20 Varint Value = 1, Hex = 01
Field #5: 28 Varint Value = 10000000000, Hex = 80-C8-AF-A0-25
```

which tells us the field numbers; so, let's try:

```cs
[ProtoContract]
class Foo
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string X { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public int Y { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(5)]
    public long Z { get; set; }
}
```

and we can generate the payload via serialization:

```cs
var foo = new Foo { X = "1324211127562612736", Y = 1, Z = 10000000000 };
using var ms = new MemoryStream();
Serializer.Serialize(ms, foo);
if (!ms.TryGetBuffer(out var buffer))
{   // in reality we should never hit this - TryGetBuffer should work
    buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(ms.ToArray());
}
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(buffer.Array, buffer.Offset, buffer.Count));
```

which outputs:

```
0A-13-31-33-32-34-32-31-31-31-32-37-35-36-32-36-31-32-37-33-36-20-01-28-80-C8-AF-A0-25
```

Comment: Your support to this library is amazing. Btw, how do you know the `ProtoMember` of X = 1, Y = 4 and Z = 5?

Comment: @derodevil that's the first bit where I decoded the bytes you posted - see how it told us the field numbers? then I just had to match up which field meant which value; it was a bit easy here since the values were so distinct. If you mean the *names* : I made those up - I can't give you sensible names, sorry

Comment: However it gives me `grpc: error unmarshalling request: proto: apc_request.InitReq: illegal tag 0 (wire type 0)`

Comment: @derodevi total guess: did you send the `.Array` from an `ArraySegment<byte>` without also considering the `.Offset` and `.Count`? That is the *underlying* buffer, which is oversized; if you need a right-sized buffer (for whatever reason): just use `ToArray()` - it'll be a bit more expensive, note

Comment: Oh my mistake. OK, it works well. Thank you so much. Great library!